# php multidimensional array key value search from two different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two different array. The array are like

first array is like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => English
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => German
                    [1] => Norwegian
                )

            [title] => file 1.xlsx
            [file_name] => 1461911750_file_test.xlsx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Hindi
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Belarusian
                )

            [title] => new files.xlsx
            [file_name] => 1461912206_file_here_files.xlsx
        )

)
```

Second array is like

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => English
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Urdu
                    [1] => Hindi
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Hindi
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Norwegian
                )

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Hindi
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => German
                )

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => English
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => German
                    [1] => Norwegian
                )

        )                

)
```

Now you can both array same key for `source_langauge` and `target_language` . The `title` and `file_name` key is available only in first array

So I want that the first array will search all the source_language and target_language from the second array and show both matching arrays and non matching arrays

So the output should be like this

```
The matching array is

[0] => Array
    (
        [source_language] => English
        [target_language] => Array
            (
                [0] => German
                [1] => Norwegian
            )

        [title] => file 1.xlsx
        [file_name] => 1461911750_file_test.xlsx
    )
```

as it has same values source language and target language in second array

The other result will show is

```
non matching array is

[0] => Array
    (
        [source_language] => Hindi
        [target_language] => Array
            (
                [0] => Belarusian
            )

        [title] => new files.xlsx
        [file_name] => 1461912206_file_here_files.xlsx
    )
```

as this source language and target languages are not found in second array.

**Update**

I have tried so far is

```
$diffs = [];

        foreach ($first_array as $a1) {
          $h1 = md5(json_encode($a1));
          $found = false;

          foreach ($second_array as $a2) {
            if (md5(json_encode($a2)) == $h1) {
              $found = true;
              break;
            }
          }


          if ( !$found ) {
            $diffs []= $a1;
          }
        }
```

But this one is not working at all

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: @RST check my updated question. I have mentioned what I have tried so far

Comment: maybe `array_diff_assoc()` will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can't compare `$h1` to `$a2` since they don't share the exact same structure.

`$h1` still has that `title` and `filename` key pair values.

No need to use `md5` and `json_encode`, since you just need to compare two string values:

```
$match = $no_match = array();
foreach($first as $f) {
    $found = false;
    foreach($second as $s) {
        if(
            $f['source_language'] === $s['source_language'] &&
            $f['target_language'] === $s['target_language']
            ) {
            $match[] = $f;
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$found) {
        $no_match[] = $f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
$arr1[0] = array('source_language'=>'English','target_language'=>array('German','Norwegian'),'title'=>'file 1.xlsx','file_name'=>'1461911750_file_test.xlsx');

$arr1[1] = array('source_language'=>'Hindi','target_language'=>array('Belarusian'),'title'=>'new files.xlsx','file_name'=>'1461912206_file_here_files.xlsx');

$arr2[0] = array('source_language'=>'English','target_language'=>array('Urdu','Hindi'));
$arr2[1] = array('source_language'=>'Hindi','target_language'=>array('Norwegian'));
$arr2[2] = array('source_language'=>'Hindi','target_language'=>array('German'));
$arr2[3] = array('source_language'=>'English','target_language'=>array('German','Norwegian'));

$result_arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr2);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($arr1);$j++)
    {
        if(($arr2[$i]['source_language'] === $arr1[$j]['source_language']) && ($arr2[$i]['target_language'] === $arr1[$j]['target_language'])) 
            $result_arr[] = $arr1[$j];
    }
}

print_r(json_encode($result_arr));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_walk` and `array_diff` functions:

```
$matched = $not_matched = [];
array_walk($array1, function($v) use($array2, &$matched, &$not_matched){
    foreach ($array2 as $item) {
        if ($v['source_language'] == $item['source_language']
            && empty(array_diff($v['target_language'], $item['target_language']))) {
            $matched[] = $v;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!in_array($v, $matched)) $not_matched[] = $v;
});

echo "Matched items:". PHP_EOL;
print_r($matched);

echo "Not-matched items:". PHP_EOL;
print_r($not_matched);
```

The output:

```
Matched items:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => English
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => German
                    [1] => Norwegian
                )

            [title] => file 1.xlsx
            [file_name] => 1461911750_file_test.xlsx
        )
)

Not-matched items:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [source_language] => Hindi
            [target_language] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Belarusian
                )

            [title] => files.xlsx
            [file_name] => 1461912206_file_here_files.xlsx
        )
)
```